# Взаимовлияние языков, кто придумал слова

Tags: этимология

> Мясо, плоть, кровь

Введением в мою дипломную (не филология) является происхождение вышеуказанных слов. Я не филолог, но мне хотелось бы понять, где все-таки образовался, например, корень "кар/кра" для слов *кровь* и *мясо* во многих европейских языках. Сравниваю русский язык и итальянский (латынь). В итальянском слово *мясо* обозначает и "мясо" и "плоть", и все плотское, физиологическое, как мне кажется, имеет несколько негативных (не без церковного влияния) оттенок. В русском все шире и ярче, хотелось бы понять истоки этого многообразия с вашей точки зрения.

Answer (score 1):

Первоисточников многих слов является санскрит. Именно там ищите корни. Конечно,это не значит что все слова пришли непосредственно из санскрита. Слова "мясо" например,Общеслав. Того же корня, что латышск. miesa «тело», др.-прус. mensā «мясо», мездра и т. д  "Школьному этимологическому словарю русского языка", (Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004 этимологическому словарю Шаинского,). Словарь не сообщает первоисточник, но,вполне вероятно, что первоисточник -он.

У брата есть книга, где автор сравнивает слова армянского и русского языка, очень много корней действительно пришли оттуда.

Comment: Санскрит сейчас не считается **непосредственным предком** европейских языков. Не буду много писать. Один из аргументов. Например, в Индии есть **неиндоевропейские** языки **дравидов**. В классическом санскрите есть влияние этих языков. В европейских языках нет. Если бы европейские языки происходили от классического санскрита, то и в них были бы следы влияния дравидов. ТО ЕСТЬ можно говорить об общем языке-предке санскрита и скажем древнеславянского, но не о том что, как вы пишете, "Первоисточников многих слов является санскрит".

Comment: О том,что вы пишете, нужны серьезные научные аргументы и доводы. Значит раньше считался, а сейчас нет.  К  тому же, я что все слова пришли из него. Он считается одним из древних языков. Он близок к праязыку.